# Cursor moves to left when typing in numericupdown

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I have a numeric up down that has some value. When I am changing this value from keyboard, after clicking of first key cursor moves to left from the entered value. For example, if I am entering '1', then cursor moves left from '1' not right to '1'.

I have done some code on value changed event.

```
 private void txtpendingAmount_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                if (decimal.Parse(txtAmtDue.Text, NumberStyles.Currency | NumberStyles.Number) == 0)
                {
                    result = calculateAmount(decimal.Parse(txtamount.Text == "" ? "0" : txtamount.Text, NumberStyles.Currency | NumberStyles.Number), decimal.Parse(txtpendingAmount.Value.ToString() == "" ? "0" : txtpendingAmount.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency | NumberStyles.Number));
                }
                else
                {
                    result = calculateAmount(decimal.Parse(txtAmtDue.Text == "" ? "0" : txtAmtDue.Text, NumberStyles.Currency), decimal.Parse(txtpendingAmount.Value.ToString() == "" ? "0" : txtpendingAmount.Value.ToString("C"), NumberStyles.Currency));
                }
                if (result == "Invalid")
                {
                    txtRemAmt.Text = "0.00";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtRemAmt.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(result).ToString("C");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
                cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(v=vs.100).aspx but your problem is most likely that you're developing in a right-to-left locale and this behavior is automatically inherited by your window.  So your actual solution may be more complex than simply toggling the behavior on a control.

Comment: I have set to position RightToLeft=No;

Comment: "I have set to position RightToLeft=No;"  ...did that fix it?

Comment: No..My problem is not solved

Answer (score 3):

i think the problem is that when you are accessing the Value, the text is evaluated, which for some reason sometimes adjusts the text and the cursor then moves.

Maybe try and access the Text, not the Value.
I had a similiar problem (in TextChanged handler though) and instead of access numericUpDown1.Value, i do `decimal.Parse(numericUpDown1.Text)` and it stops moving the cursor.